# Compacting file geodatabases for editing performance?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, editing, file-geodatabase, performance

Is there a way to quantify the effect of compacting your ESRI file geodatabase(s) on editing performance? I currently use ArcInfo(10.0).

I have a 769 MB fgdb that holds my most used/edited datalayers either in feature datasets or stand alone feature class(es) and am considering a redesign of how I have things set up for my most common workflows and editing tasks. Other than this [link](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Compacting_file_and_personal_geodatabases/018s0000000s000000/) to the pertinent ESRI's help page, I really haven't been able to find anything pertaining to this question.

Comment: It's extremely difficult to quantify anything without a copy of the data involved, yet the link you cite gives a great deal of information.  What more do you need?

Comment: @vince...the link tells me the "what" but I am more curious about the result of compacting. I am just considering rewriting some of my data maintenance scripts that run on a weekly basis to add a compacting fgdb component. The above mentioned fgdb does exhibit some editing lag on occasion and i was curious if there was a way, other than just compacting it frequently to see if it gets better, to look at performance improvement. I guess a before and after value/speed or what have you that is appropriate...

Comment: No one can know what the impact of compressing your data will be until you do so.  As the document explains, compressing removes gaps in data files marked as deleted.  Since every editing pattern is unique, the space recovered is not predictable, and the performance impact of that change is unknowable.  You can publish your performance change metrics, but they would likely change week to week, and it won't have any more bearing on my system(s) than mine would have on yours.

Comment: @vince...that makes sense and thank you for the explanation, but fgdb compression and fgdb compaction are two different things in ESRI's view, aren't they?.

Comment: s/compress/compact/g

Comment: @vince...could you resubmit your "no one can know..." comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to predict the exact impact of compacting your data until you do so. As the document explains, compacting removes gaps in data files due to edited rows being marked as deleted. Since every site's editing pattern is unique, the space recovered is not predictable, and the performance impact of that change is unknowable. You can publish your performance change metrics, but they would likely change week to week (depending on the number and kinds of edits required), and they won't have any more bearing on my system(s) than mine would have on yours.

Answer (score 3):

Compaction reorders records and frees up space, compression converts the geodatabase to read-only format.

As Vince has commented, the only way to know if it has a beneficial effect is to try it. If your FGDB is heavily used with lots of additions *and* deletions, then compacting may well provide a benefit to performance. If you only ever *add* data then it may not make much (if any) difference.

Comment: I understand the differences between compaction and compression on a database, I was just wondering if there was a way to "put a number on" the before/after effect of compaction and how it would alter any editing speed, or lag, on this particular database i use.

Comment: I think @spg answered your question.  Can you please check it as answered. As was already pointed out, exploring and analyzing the subtleties of a file geodatabase read/write/commit speeds might be difficult to objectively quantify.FGDB is a personal geodatabase suitable for desktop computing environments. If subtle performance increase is of utmost importance you may want to explore a true enterprise Spatial RDBMS for your backend.

Comment: The only way I can think of to "put a number on it" would be to run some tests; create a gdb, add data, do a number of edits/deletes/adds, check the size gain, then compact to see the difference. Repeat over and over. Keeping track of the number of vertices and attributes modified might be useful to help establish if any relationship exists with respect to space savings. It all depends how much editing you do, especially deletions, if you add and delete a lot then you will gain the most from compaction.